# Delete rows for matching columns with a conditional in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

In two datasets, there is a column of matching values (one file has many entries for each value). How can I delete rows in which other two columns should be compared?

For example, Data2 describes the names and conditions that should be set to Data1. If the number for any Adam entry is lower than the threshold 11, delete that row from Data1.
Data1:

```
Name     Number
Adam     10  
Adam     5 
Adam     1 
Adam     20 
Bob      4  
Bob      11 
Bob      30 
Bob      50
```

Data2:

```
Name     Threshold
Adam     11
Bob      20
```

Desired output:

```
Name     Number
Adam     20 
Bob      30 
Bob      50
```

Comment: "deleting rows" isn't really a thing in R (functional mindset), searching for "filtering rows" might reveal existing questions/answers.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data1)
Data1[Data2, on = .(Name, Number >= Threshold), .(Name, Number = x.Number)]

#    Name Number
# 1: Adam     20
# 2:  Bob     30
# 3:  Bob     50
```

Data

```
Data1 <- data.frame(
  Name = rep(c("Adam", "Bob"), each = 4),
  Number = c(10L, 5L, 1L, 20L, 4L, 11L, 30L, 50L)
)
Data2 <- data.frame(Name = c("Adam", "Bob"), Threshold = c(11L, 20L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `merge` the two dataframes and select rows above `Threshold`.

This can be done in base R :

```
subset(merge(df1, df2, by = 'Name') , Number >= Threshold)[names(df1)]
```

Or using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = 'Name') %>%
  filter(Number >= Threshold) %>%
  select(-Threshold)

#  Name Number
#1 Adam     20
#2  Bob     30
#3  Bob     50
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in `base R` by subsetting:

```
Data1[-which(Data1$Name=="Adam" & Data1$Number <= Data2$Number[Data2$Name=="Adam"] |
              Data1$Name=="Bob" & Data1$Number <= Data2$Number[Data2$Name=="Bob"]),]
  Name Number
4 Adam     20
7  Bob     30
8  Bob     50
```